# Display a dialog within the main window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qdialog

The code below creates an empty dialog when `Hello!` is pressed:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        toyButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello!")
        layout.addWidget(toyButton)
        toyButton.clicked.connect(self.showdialog)

    def showdialog(self):
        d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        d.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        d.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        d.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

How can I force the dialog to appear *within* the main window instead of having it floating around as an independent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to give the dialog a parent widget: `d = QtWidgets.QDialog(self.centralWidget())`. `self` is also a valid parent; pick your favorite!

You could also add `d` to the layout: `self.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(d)`; 
although this second one does not respect your modality+exec.

Here's the full code comparing both methods:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        toyButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello!")
        layout.addWidget(toyButton)
        toyButton.clicked.connect(self.showdialog)

        toyButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello2!")
        layout.addWidget(toyButton2)
        toyButton2.clicked.connect(self.showdialog2)

    def showdialog(self):
        d = QtWidgets.QDialog(self.centralWidget())
        d.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        d.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        d.exec_()

    def showdialog2(self):
        d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        d.setWindowTitle("Dialog2")   # window title won't be seen...
        d.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        QtWidgets.QPushButton('Dialog2', parent=d) # ... so we add a little something
        self.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(d)
        d.exec_()
```